# Using web.py return a post request and do further processing after the response

Tags: python, post

I am using web.py to return a protocol buffer response from a post request and response time is critical.  I have some writes to redis that I would like to do after the post response. rather than before.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
class index:
    def POST(self):
    return pPbuffer
    r.set('a','b')
```

So, how can I modify the code so I can I can return as quickly as possible but doing post cleanup (no pun intended).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using wsgi or something as server you could use yield to generate contents time after time and the browser will receive them in sort.

For your example:

```
class index:
    def POST(self):
        yield pPbuffer
        r.set('a','b')
```

And [this](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/uwsgistatus.py) is a good example which is doing it this way.

Comment: I am using fasgcgi with nginx.